# Modal popup is moving to the left side after several clicks inside of modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made one modal popup in my project..its working fine. but the problem here is when I click inside of the popup several times the modal popup is moving to the left side.

And I didn't find the exact solution for this..searched a lot on a web. but I didn't get the solution.

Here is my modal code:

```css
.followup-modal {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 380px;
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-header {
        background-color: #1c3f94;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-title {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 8px 5px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-content {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-top: none;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-body {
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-body #reminderdate {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 2px;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-body #reminderText {
        width: 294px !important;
        margin-left: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 4px;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-body #reminderclosereason {
        width: 90%;
        margin-left: 6px;
        padding: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-footer {
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .followup-modal .modal-footer .defaultbutton {
        padding: 2px 10px;
    }
    .popup-dragable {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        z-index: 99999;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 99999 !important;
    }
    #reminder.popup-layout {
        left: 0;
    }
    #reminder.popup-layout .modal-body {
        height: 80px;
    }
    #reminder.popup-layout .followup-modal .modal-footer {
        height: 32px;
    }
    .reminder {
        margin-top: -1px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="popup-dragable hideElement" style="display: block;">
        <div id="reminderPopup"><div id="reminder" class="popup-layout">
        <form id="reminderForm" method="post">
            <div class="modal followup-modal ui-draggable" id="reminderPopupdrag" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title">select_followup</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="errorInPopup" class="error displayInlineBlock"></div>
                            <table class="width100percent">
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label><input type="radio" name="reminder" id="reminder-1" value="1" class="element full-width verticalAlignMiddle reminder">close_with_reminder</label>                                </td>
                                    <td class="textAlignRight">
                                        <input type="text" id="reminderdate" name="reminderdate" class="marginRight5 displayNone">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <input type="text" name="reminderText" id="reminderText" value="" class="element displayNone width-full marginTop5" placeholder="add_remark_here">                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <label><input type="radio" name="reminder" id="reminder-2" value="2" class="element full-width verticalAlignMiddle reminder">close_without_reminder</label>                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <select name="reminderclosereason" id="reminderclosereason" class="element displayNone width100percent">
        <option value="">Select value</option>
        <option value="6">Advertisements</option>
        <option value="4">Another reason:</option>
        <option value="17">Checking  financial terms and conditions</option>
        <option value="16">Company not leasable</option>
        <option value="18">Future potential clients  </option>
        <option value="20">Offer is of vehicle type in which we do not do business</option>
        <option value="12">Open application</option>
        <option value="13">Order</option>
        <option value="10">Other ticket already in progress</option>
        <option value="11">Out of office reply </option>
        <option value="50">Portal, ad removed, payment, offer withdrawn</option>
        <option value="7">SPAM</option>
        <option value="9">Unsubscribe MFO Mailing</option>
        <option value="2">Vehicle/part is sold (indicate order number!)</option>
        <option value="8">Vehicle/part not on stock (is looking for something else)</option>
        <option value="1">Vehicles too expensive</option>
    </select>                                </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="submit" name="send" id="sendPreview" value="Save" class="defaultbutton displayNone">                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

and when it moves to left it is changing this line like below

```
<div class="modal followup-modal ui-draggable" id="reminderPopupdrag" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="left: 572.5px; top: 141.2px;">
```

AS I found the problem is Happening because of this line

```
$('#reminderPopupdrag').draggable();
```

if I remove this line the problem is not occurring.

Can you guys please help me to solve this issue..struggling from past few days to find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix that is to apply draggable() to the modal-dialog class instead:

instead of this line `$('#reminderPopupdrag').draggable();`

i have used `$(".modal-dialog").draggable();`

And now the problem is solved.